# Differentiate whether it's a redirect: or a normal request in HandlerInterceptorAdaptor

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How do I differentiate between a redirect: or not in HandlerInterceptorAdaptor.preHandle()? I need to clear a session attribute every new request excepts it's a redirect: from controller class.

e.g.

**Interceptor class**

```
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, Object handler) throws Exception {
        //CHECK whether it's a redirect:, if NO then clear session attribute.
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        session.removeAttribute("attributeKey");
    }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/detail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private String viewDetails(HttpSession session, ...) {
    //program logic here
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/updatedetail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private String updateDetails(HttpSession session, ...) {
    //program logic here
    //set session attribute
    session.setAttribute("attributeKey", someobject);

    //redirect, but i want the session attribute to be visible to the page instead of cleared by interceptor
    return "redirect:detail";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
model.addAttribute("attributeKey", someObject);
return "redirect:detail";
```

And to hide `attributeKey`:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView">
    <property name="exposeModelAttributes" value="false"/>
    <property name="url" value="/detail"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks.. does it means for every url i need to have a mapping?

Comment: I am a bit out of Spring. There should be an annotation too for instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can change this line into you code. 
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);